# React navigation v5 is released to production?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, routes, navigation, react-navigation

I once saw a yellow alert when reactivating v4 navigation, saying it would be archived and the focus would be v5.
I am planning an app and wanted to use v5. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Use V5, it’s great. I’d recommend (almost) never to build something on a package that’s already deprecated.